# Why does .reshape(a, b) != .reshape(b, a).T?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape, transpose

I ran into this problem whilst flattening images. Consider the following array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[[1, 2],
                     [3, 4]],
                    [[1, 2],
                     [3, 4]]])
>>> arr.shape
(2, 2, 2)
```

I wish to reshape this into an 4x2 array **where each vertical slice is a flattened image**.

##### 1. Using `.reshape(2, 4).T`

This achieves the desired result

```
>>> arr_flatten = arr.reshape(2, 4).T
>>> arr_flatten
[[1 1]
 [2 2]
 [3 3]
 [4 4]]
```

##### 2. Using `.reshape(4, 2)`

This does not achieve the desired result

```
>>> arr_flatten = arr.reshape(4, 2)
>>> arr_flatten
[[1 2]
 [3 4]
 [1 2]
 [3 4]]
```

Why does this second approach not work?

Comment: From the docs `You can think of reshaping as first raveling the array (using the given index order), then inserting the elements from the raveled array into the new array using the same kind of index ordering as was used for the raveling.`.  Play with different shapes starting with `np.arange(8)`

Comment: Another way to say it: any reshape, whatever its parameter, preserve the order of the data (the order in which you would write each value on the screen when you print the array stay the same after any reshape).

Comment: `.T` on the other hand does not preserve that order (it is even its only job to change that order).

Comment: So, unsurprisingly, `data.reshape(whatever)` can't be the same as `data.reshape(whatever).T`. The problem in not in the `reshape` part. Again, they have no effect on the data order. You could chain 20 `.reshape` on each side, they would change nothing to that order (again by "order" I mean the order in which the data are printed on screen). The problem is in `.T`. There is a `.T` on one side, not on the other. Knowing that it is fatal that whatever `reshape` are, arrays have to be different, since they don't even have the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two reshapes are creating the array differently. Think of `.reshape(2,4)` as traversing the array while counting elements and every time it gets to 4 it creates a new row and restarts the count. So, with the count in parenthesis, it goes 1 (1), 2 (2), 3 (3), 4 (4) *new row* 1 (1), 2 (2), 3 (3), 4 (4). For `.reshape(4,2)`, it counts up to 2 and starts a new row. So it goes, 1 (1), 2 (2) *new row* 3 (1), 4 (2) *new row* 1 (1), 2 (2) *new row* 3 (1), 4 (1).

Hence, `.reshape(2,4)` produces

```py
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

And `.reshape(4,2)` produces.

```py
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

Clearly, their transposes aren't equal. As for why one gives the right answer, that all comes down to the meaning of the data and how it is ordered. In this case, because the images are in axis 0, the `.reshape(2,4)` traverses the entire axis 0 before creating a new row, so it gives the correct result.

Comment: So the way `.reshape()` works is like reading words off a page (left to right and then top to bottom) and then writing them onto a different size page, in the order you read them?

Comment: With the default arguments, yes. If you look at the [reshape documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), there is an `order="C"` default kwarg, which is what tells it to go left-to-right and top-to-bottom (since that's how arrays in C are defined). If that were changed to `order="F"`, then it would be Fortran-style and go top-to-bottom and left-to-right, (`.reshape(2,4)` would then be `[[1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 4]]`).

Comment: @MagnusSesodia : to say it pragmatically: when you print the array, reshape never change the order of the numbers. It only changes where `[` and `]` are. `.T` does. So you can ignore all the `.reshape` to answer your question: since on one since you have a `.T` and on another you don't, that means that on one side you have a different order for the number of the array, and on the other, you have the same order as in the initial array (only with different `[ / ]` places)

Comment: Good explanation, it's also worth it looking into the different strides of each array to understand the difference better